# Recursive sorting of objects from the same table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sorting, collections

My data is like the table below (I have excluded any values not do with sorting order for simplicity).

```
ID     POSITION     PARENT     HASCHILDREN
------------------------------------------
1         1           0            False
2         3           0            True
3         2           0            False
4         1           2            False
5         2           2            False
```

What I want to do is recursively sort this data by position into objects. The object I have is like this

```
public class ExampleObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
    public List<ExampleObject> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The object above is recursive in the sense that it can always have its own children even though in this example it is only 2 layers deep. I don't know how to structure the result on SO but here's the JSON for what I would want the result to be

```
    [
        {
            ID: 1,
            Position: 1,
            Parent: 0,
            HasChildren: false,
            Children: []
        },
        {
            ID: 3,
            Position: 2,
            Parent: 0,
            HasChildren: false,
            Children: []
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            Position: 3,
            Parent: 0,
            HasChildren: true,
            Children: [
                {                        
                    ID: 4,
                    Position: 1,
                    Parent: 2,
                    HasChildren: false,
                    Children: []
                },
                {                        
                    ID: 5,
                    Position: 2,
                    Parent: 2,
                    HasChildren: false,
                    Children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I don't really know where to start, what I do know is that the lists will not be very big (10-20) items including children and *should* be mostly sorted if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a Common Table Expression (CTE for short). With these you can get recursive queries. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182082/recursive-sql-query-t-sql) has a good example.

Comment: That looks interesting but I'm struggling to apply it to my scenario. It seems those are only very basic examples and I'm not seeing what the TSQL is actually doing. The marked answer's query results are in the same order that it added them to the table.